# How to copy the data of current row using VueJS in modal?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently using vuejs for my project. And what I need is when I click a row from the table, a modal will show and fill the form out based on the data that is in a clicked row. But, my code is not working for it. Please see my code below.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#roleContainer',
  data: {
      roles: [
        { display_name: 'user', description: 'user', created_at: '2020/02/20' },
        { display_name: 'mod', description: 'mod', created_at: '2020/02/21' }
      ],
      id: '',
      display_name: '',
      description: ''
  },

  methods: {
      openEditModal(role){
          $('#formModal').modal('show');
          console.log(role);
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="roleContainer">
  <table class="table table-striped with-border">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Display Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Created at</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="role in roles" @click="openEditModal" class="pointer">
            <td v-text="role.display_name"></td>
            <td v-text="role.description"></td>
            <td v-text="role.created_at"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="formModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Create Role</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Display Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="display_name" v-model="display_name" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Description</label>
     <input type="text" name="description" v-model="description" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="createNewRole">Save</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr v-for="role in roles" @click="openEditModal" class="pointer">
        <td v-text="role.display_name"></td>
        <td v-text="role.description"></td>
        <td v-text="role.created_at"></td>
</tr>
```

here, you should pass the parameter, role. for example,

```
@click="openEditModal(role)"
```

and then, in openEditModal function,

```
this.display_name = role.display_name;
this.description = role.description;
```

I hope it is helpful for you

Comment: This is correct but, I just needed to edit from `display_name` to `this.display_name`. Please update too.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Vue directives, the expressions are evaluated in the context of Vue, so you don't need to wrap things in `{}`.

`@click` is just shorthand for `v-on:click` directive so the same rules apply.

In your case, simply use `@click="addToCount(item.contactID)"`

Replace your table body with this.

```
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="role in roles" @click="openEditModal(role)" class="pointer">
        <td v-text="role.display_name"></td>
        <td v-text="role.description"></td>
        <td v-text="role.created_at"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```